# VISUAL STUDIO .NET MVC Cannot Scaffold a razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

Working with .net5 MVC app, right clicking in a controller's action and selecting
**add view --> Razor view(Not empty)**

[image]

After clicking **Add** the following error appears :

[image]

Scaffolding was working well until about 2 days ago.
Any ideas what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: update the version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

navigate to NuGet packages and make sure you have a (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design) and you should make sure that is the version above 5.0.0

if you already have make sure the build go without fails and just restart the visual studio and it should works.

Comment: Tried that . Didn't work !  Thank you ! I finally  re-installed .net and visual studio and problem solved. It was i think one of that small bugs that waste your precious time trying to solve them instead of pure coding !!!!